# Drools: Any value of a String list is member of another String list

Tags: validation, drools

I'm having troubles to find how to check in drools if any value of a String list is member of another String list.

```
when

//any value of stringList1 member of stringList2

then 

// whatever...
```

I guess, I may use the forall operation, but still couldn't find the way. Any help..?

Let's say my validation bean is something like:

```
 public final class StringListValidationBean {

   private List<String> stringList1;
   private List<String> stringList2;
   //... gets & sets

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
rule someString
when
    $l1: List()
    $s: String() from $l1
    List( hashCode > $l1.hashCode, this contains $s )
then
    System.out.println( "both: " + $s );
end
```

If using the ValidationBean is essential, the lists can be referenced from within the bean:

```
$vb: ValidationBean( $sl1: stringList1 )
$s: String() from $sl1
ValidationBean( this == $vb, stringList2 contains $s )
```

This will fire for each String contained in both lists.

Another approach would be a DRL function that uses List.retainAll(), something like

```
function boolean (List l1, List l2){
    List is = new ArrayList( l1 );
    is.retainAll( l2 );
    return is.size() > 0;
}
```

Or let the function return the List with the common strings.